# Горизонтальная линия tr

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать ниже 1 и 2 ячейки `border-bottom:1px solid black` во всю ширину таблицы и что бы она была не прерывистой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ко всей таблице применить свойство border-spacing: 0;